# Handling -no records found- in Oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

The following Oracle query supposed to return rows of field `num`, when there are records. When no records are found I would like it to return `N/A` as display value and 0 as return value field.

```
select num display_value, num return_value from cells 
  WHERE ss = 4
UNION ALL SELECT "N/A" display_value, 0 return_value from dual 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CELLS WHERE ss = 4)
```

This doesn't work when no records found, because `num` is type of `NUMBER` and "N/A" is not `NUMBER`. Question is how can I amend query to work? Maybe there is better way to do it?

Comment: So replace 'N/A' with 0

Comment: This will add the `N/A`  row every time. Is this desired?

Comment: @Mihai, I would like `N/A` to be in string representation, not numerical.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux: Apparently no. I was hoping WHERE NOT EXISTS will add it whenever no rows found.

Comment: @Pablo Right, I've missed that part at the end of the query. Sorry...

Comment: @Pablo ... and I missed the fact that you (too) where using the wrong quotes: `"N/A"` instead of `'N/A'`. The former is for [schema object qualifier or name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) while the later is for [string literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/literal.htm#LNPLS01326).

Comment: Yes, I missed that.. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST` or `TO_CHAR`?

> ```
> select to_char(num) numdisplay_value, num return_value from cells 
>   WHERE ss = 4
> UNION ALL SELECT 'N/A' display_value, 0 return_value from dual 
>   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CELLS WHERE ss = 4)
> ```

Maybe (look at your execution plan), you will get better results by using a CTE instead.

At the very least, this second solution will more readable (to my taste) and probably more maintainable according to the *don't repeat yourself* principle, as you will have to write the `where` clause only once:

> ```
> with cte as (select to_char(num) numdisplay_value, num return_value 
>              from cells 
>              WHERE ss = 4)
>
> select * from cte
> union all SELECT 'N/A', 0 from dual 
>       WHERE not exists(select * from cte)
> ```

Comment: The `TO_CHAR` method gives the following error: `ORA-00904: "N/A": invalid identifier`

Comment: @Pablo *typo!* I used `"`  instead of `'`. Should be fixed now.